# Javascript Date Now (UTC) in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

My brain must be utterly fried, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the current date and time in UTC formatted as a string. No matter what I do, I just get local.

I have the following function which returns the date in the correct format, but it's always local.

```js
let datenow = new Date;

console.log(datenow); // "2021-07-28T18:11:11.282Z"
console.log(generateDatabaseDateTime(datenow)); // "2021-07-28 14:11:33"

function generateDatabaseDateTime(date) {
  const p = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    year:'numeric',
    month:'2-digit',
    day:'2-digit',
    hour:'2-digit',
    minute:'2-digit',
    second:'2-digit',
    hour12: false
  }).formatToParts(date).reduce((acc, part) => {
    acc[part.type] = part.value;
      return acc;
  }, {});

  return `${p.year}-${p.month}-${p.day} ${p.hour}:${p.minute}:${p.second}`;
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Just use `date.getUTC<Year/Month/etc>`? Or `date.toISOString().replace("T", " ")`.

Comment: Just add `timeZone:'UTC'` to the options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should use in-built `toISOString` function to covert it to ISO date format and remove not required data using string manipulation.

```js
let datenow = new Date();

console.log(datenow); // "2021-07-28T18:11:11.282Z"
console.log(generateDatabaseDateTime(datenow)); // "2021-07-28 14:11:33"

function generateDatabaseDateTime(date) {
  return date.toISOString().replace("T"," ").substring(0, 19);
}
```

Ideally solution should be to use momentjs or dayjs library.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I would have used momentjs or another library, but it just seemed like overkill for this simple script I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way can be getting each UTC unit from the `new Date()` object and creating the desired string.

```js
const date = new Date();

const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
const month = String(date.getUTCMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // Month is 0-based
const day = String(date.getUTCDate()).padStart(2, '0');

const hour = String(date.getUTCHours()).padStart(2, '0');
const minute = String(date.getUTCMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
const second = String(date.getUTCSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
        
const strDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

console.log(strDate);
```

Adding a valuable suggestion by RobG, as sometimes comments get deleted:

> Somewhat simpler: `new Date().toLocaleString('en-CA',{timeZone:'UTC', hour12:false}).replace(',','')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for letting me know that padStart exists.

Comment: @josh—Somewhat simpler: `new Date().toLocaleString('en-CA',{timeZone:'UTC', hour12:false}).replace(',','')`. :-0

Comment: Thanks, @RobG for the valuable suggestion. For this specific problem, indeed your solution is the best solution in my opinion. In fact, I started with writing the exact solution which has been accepted (nevertheless, yours is still the best) but then I changed my mind and I thought to write this way. The reason why I wrote this way is, it gives flexibility to arrange the units in any manner e.g. `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer as well that RobG suggested.

```js
let datenow = new Date;

console.log(datenow); // "2021-07-28T18:11:11.282Z"
console.log(generateDatabaseDateTime(datenow)); // "2021-07-28 14:11:33"

function generateDatabaseDateTime(date) {
  const p = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    year:'numeric',
    month:'2-digit',
    day:'2-digit',
    hour:'2-digit',
    minute:'2-digit',
    second:'2-digit',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone:'UTC'
  }).formatToParts(date).reduce((acc, part) => {
    acc[part.type] = part.value;
      return acc;
  }, {});

  return `${p.year}-${p.month}-${p.day} ${p.hour}:${p.minute}:${p.second}`;
}
```